# splitbib example leads to runaway argument

Tags: bibliographies, splitbib

I am trying to split a simple bibliography into two parts for different kinds of sources. The splitbib package should do this easy enough. Unfortunately, the minimum example from the documentation(http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/splitbib/splitbib.pdf) as well as the following MWE lead to a runaway argument error where the compiler somehow does not find the end of the first bibitem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{splitbib}

\title{Splitbib MWE}
\author{Scipio}

\begin{category}[A]{First Category}
\SBentries{T,S}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second Category}
\SBentries{W,X}
\end{category}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Here we cite stuff}
Obviously \cite{T} because of \cite{W}. Considering\cite{X} we conclude\cite{S}


\begin{thebibliography}{42}
\bibitem{T} Some Author, Some Paper, 1975
\bibitem{S} Some other Author, Some Book, 1964
\bibitem{W} Some Website, 12.06.2018
\bibitem{X} Some other Website 14.07.2017
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package code requires a blank line after each bibitem (which seems a rather fragile requirement)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{splitbib}

\title{Splitbib MWE}
\author{Scipio}

\begin{category}[A]{First Category}
\SBentries{T,S}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second Category}
\SBentries{W,X}
\end{category}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{Here we cite stuff}
Obviously \cite{T} because of \cite{W}. Considering\cite{X} we conclude\cite{S}

\makeatletter
\begin{thebibliography}{42}
\bibitem{T} Some Author, Some Paper, 1975

\bibitem{S} Some other Author, Some Book, 1964

\bibitem{W} Some Website, 12.06.2018

\bibitem{X} Some other Website 14.07.2017

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are other packages that exploit that feature; BibTeX always adds a blank line between entries in the `.bbl` file it produces.

Comment: @egreg I suspect I've written some:-) but still it would be safer to use a newEnvioron-style collection of tokens until the next \bibitem or \end{thebibliography} even if that complicates the parsing a bit